# Execute function depending on href location - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, href

Okay so I have the following variable...

```
var href = document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
```

...and wish to use it to execute this:

```
window.onload = function(){
if (href = "example.html"){
 /* do something */
 }
```

I only use Vanilla Javascript so if there is a solution to the above, It's greatly appreciated if its not jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: This question is different from **"The 3 different equals" asked by Strawberry** because its answers include jQuery, while this question is for only Vanilla JavaScript solutions. Additionally, this question is specific to utilizing href in the execution of a function, while the question asked by Strawberry rather generalizes the purpose of =, ==, and ===, and does not specifically address whether or not using such code would enable the use of href for executing a function - moreover, there is no mention of href in the question asked by Strawberry.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. Test with `===` instead:

```
var href = document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
window.onload = function(){
if (href === "example.html"){
  /* do something */
}
```